# Outlook Office Addin not showing HTML page in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, outlook, office-addins

This is my div:

```
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

and this is my code behind in js:

```
function jsonParser(sender) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://MYURL/customers/outlook?email=" + sender + "&jsonp=true",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (htmlPage) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = htmlPage.htmlText;
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the code that calls it:

```
function detectActionsForMe() {
    var item = Office.cast.item.toItemRead(Office.context.mailbox.item);
    var sender = item.sender.emailAddress;
    jsonParser(sender);
}
```

I can't actually get the downloaded html page to show up in the Outlook (2016) addin window. I already tried using an iframe but I was obtaining nothing, neither.

I am sure about the page I am getting, I find just weird that it won't show up in the outlook box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was missing, thanks to http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Basically, I just added the following, to the ajax call:

```
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "jsonp",
```

and it all worked! :)